# AlertDialog MultiChoiceItems Listener problems

Tags: android, android-1.5-cupcake

I am currently using the AlertDialog.builder to create a multichoice list for the user (checkboxes).  This works great, except we want one of the buttons to deselect all of the others in the list.

```
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(list, checked,
  new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
     int item, boolean isChecked) {

    if(item == ANY_ITEM_BUT_0)
    {

     ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().setItemChecked(0, false);

    }
   }
  });
```

When using "true" it will successfully check the box, but when using false it does not uncheck it (unless i have manually set it to true before hand.)  Is there a separate listener I should be using to detect when a user clicks these?  It seems to me that there are two checkmarks set, one by the "setItemChecked(0, true);", and one by actually selecting it.

This has been driving me nuts for a couple days now, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

OH!!! I forget it to ensure deselect you must change checked to null ;), I had the same issue.

```
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(list, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
...
```

Comment: You have saved me a lot of time :) Thanks! I was setting all items with false, but it seems that null is all i needed!

Answer (score 3):

To deselect the other items it works fine::

```
if(item == ANY_ITEM_BUT_0){    
   for(int i=0; i<items.length;i++){  
            if (item != ANY_ITEM_BUT_0)                             
           ((AlertDialog)dialog).getListView().setItemChecked(i, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont think you can change the values in the list since the list-items (checkboxes) are controlled by the builder-object. However, you could simply make the dialog re-initiate when the first item is clicked... by dismissing the dialog that is showing, and create a new one....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a check box to not be checked and you need to set the `checkedItems` array on the call to `setMultiChoiceItems()`, you need to set the checked array items to false as well.  Make sure your checked array is final so you can access it in the listener.

```
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(list, checked,
new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
 int item, boolean isChecked) {

if(isChecked && item == ANY_ITEM_BUT_0)
{
   for(int i=0; i<list.length;i++){  
      if (i != ANY_ITEM_BUT_0) {   
       checked[i] = false;                          
       ((AlertDialog)dialog).getListView().setItemChecked(i, false);
        } 
     }
   }
  }
});
```