# Check / uncheck items in OnMultiChoiceClickListener.onClick?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm creating a multiple choice `AlertDialog`, using `AlertDialog.Builder` and `setMultiChoiceItems`.

I want to check / uncheck items from inside the `OnMultiChoiceClickListener`, but I can't find how.

Here's my code:

```
final List<User> users = Util.getUsers();
final String[] names = new String[users.size()];
final boolean[] checked = new boolean[users.size()];
for (int i=0; i < names.length; i++) {
    names[i] = users.get(i).getName();
    checked[i] = selectedUsers.contains(users.get(i).getId());
}
new AlertDialog.Builder(EventFormActivity.this)
    .setTitle(R.string.schedule_for)
    .setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            updateScheduleForText();
        }
    })
    .setMultiChoiceItems(names, checked, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) selectedUsers.add(users.get(which).getId());
            else selectedUsers.remove((Integer) users.get(which).getId());
            // check or uncheck other items? how?
        }
     })
     .show();
```

The only way I see that I could do this is implement a custom `ListAdapter`, or even a custom dialog-themed `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

The DialogInterface that you get in the OnClick Method should be an AlertDialog.  You can then use the [getButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#getButton%28int%29) function to get the button objects and you should be able to manipulate the various buttons from there.

EDIT:
I think I understand the issue now, you are going to want to work with the [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#getListView%28%29)  While putting together an example I found this [already solved on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067641/how-uncheck-items-in-alertdialog-setmultichoiceitems)  That example show you how to check/uncheck the list items from your OnMultiChoiceClickListener

Comment: I don't need to alter the buttons. I need to change the checked state of one or more of the choices.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : [How uncheck items in AlertDialog (setMultiChoiceItems)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067641/how-uncheck-items-in-alertdialog-setmultichoiceitems).

```
AskMeSelected[which] = false;
alertDialogList.setItemChecked(which, false);
```

Be sure to also set the corresponding position of boolean array to false.