# Uncheck AlertDialog check list box programmaticaly

Tags: android, checkbox, android-alertdialog

I need to uncheck checked checkbox programmaticaly, but the check list is in dialog. Does this changes solution? What I have so far:

```
CharSequence[] items = itemList.toArray(new CharSequence[itemList.size()]);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Select categories");

builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null,
new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
  if (isChecked){
    if(chosenCat.size() < 10){
      chosenCat.add(items[which].toString());
    }else{
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Max 10 categories to compare.",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      //uncheck
      items.isChecked = false; // --> wrong
      chosenCat.remove(items[which].toString());
    }
  }else{
    chosenCat.remove(items[which].toString());
  }
}
});
```

Comment: Actually what you want? you want to  show list with alert box ? you can use your list view as alert dialog using theme in manifest ..

Comment: View the previous post fot [setItmChecked][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067641/how-uncheck-items-in-alertdialog-setmultichoiceitems

Comment: See previous post [SetItemCheck][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067641/how-uncheck-items-in-alertdialog-setmultichoiceitems

Answer (score 3):

I've missed this line

```
((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().setItemChecked(which, false);
```

after

```
checkboxStatusArray[1] = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `boolean[]` into `builder.setMultiChoiceItems` which indicates checkbox status(checked/unchecked) for the checkboxes added respectively.Try this sample code

```
boolean[] checkboxStatusArray = {true,false};

CharSequence[] items = itemList.toArray(new CharSequence[itemList.size()]);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
builder.setTitle("Select categories");

builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, checkboxStatusArray,
new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {


                      checkboxStatusArray[1] = true;//This line will enable second check box



     }
 });

builder.show();
```

Comment: final boolean[] checkboxStatusArray = {true,false};
   
   CharSequence[] items = {"one","two","three"};
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
   builder.setTitle("Select categories");

   builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, checkboxStatusArray,
   new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

                         checkboxStatusArray[1] = true;//This line will enable second check box

        }
    });
   builder.show();

I can't get it to work. :(

Comment: you are adding 3 checkbox items, so add 3 boolean values in checkboxStatusArray

Comment: ya..it is checked because of the line `checkboxStatusArray[1] = true;` What you wanted? you can modify this according to you.

Comment: In the debuger after "checkboxStatusArray[0] = false;" line is executed checkboxStatusArray[0] stays on true; -- Do I need refresh or something?

Comment: This code works only when you click your checkbox(any).Supppose you click your first checkbox and if your second checkbox is unchecked then this code will check your second checkbox.

Comment: Missing: ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().setItemChecked(which, false);